# web3.py No matching entries for 'tuple' in decoder registry

Tags: events, web3.py

- Version: master (6a90a26ea12e5a789834c9cd6a7ae6d302648f88)
- Python: 3.9
- OS: osx
- `pip freeze`
  https://gist.github.com/Th0rgal/bb866886af6224af5e89bd64ba0b99bf

#### What was wrong?

It seems I am not able to decode events from my contract.

Solidity event:

```
    event PlotChange(bytes32 indexed location, Plot newPlot);
```

My python code:

```py
        print("CODEC:", codec)
        print("LOG:", log)
        evt = get_event_data(codec, abi, log)
        print(evt)
```

Error code (and output):

```
CODEC: <eth_abi.codec.ABICodec object at 0x102929070>
LOG: AttributeDict({'address': '0x40B24f2A0F58E050233A3C19eb42f297df069bB8', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x1af88b407390f70365dfe6590fe97011549fb683cb4619e6b4674f02fffc838a'), 'blockNumber': 1295972, 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061dc05430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 'logIndex': 0, 'removed': False, 'topics': [HexBytes('0xb0b3ea803f5e36351f6eb0eec7e662cac0949697e039219aea060eb29f64a0d0'), HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')], 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x4cb2c4dfe12d69ac27a3fb3379387dcbabd1afd87e13f0d7f587c07a2d27e342'), 'transactionIndex': 0})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 324, in _retry_web3_call
    return end_block, func(start_block, end_block)
  File "test.py", line 180, in _fetch_events
    return _fetch_events_for_all_contracts(self.web3,
  File "test.py", line 405, in _fetch_events_for_all_contracts
    evt = get_event_data(codec, abi, log)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/nix/store/czlg5442w24w6mbam890wcgkjf6vqgxd-python3-3.8.12-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/_utils/events.py", line 241, in get_event_data
    decoded_log_data = abi_codec.decode_abi(log_data_types, log_data)
  File "/nix/store/czlg5442w24w6mbam890wcgkjf6vqgxd-python3-3.8.12-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_abi/codec.py", line 173, in decode_abi
    decoders = [
  File "/nix/store/czlg5442w24w6mbam890wcgkjf6vqgxd-python3-3.8.12-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_abi/codec.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    self._registry.get_decoder(type_str)
  File "/nix/store/czlg5442w24w6mbam890wcgkjf6vqgxd-python3-3.8.12-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_abi/registry.py", line 469, in get_decoder
    return self._get_registration(self._decoders, type_str)
  File "/nix/store/czlg5442w24w6mbam890wcgkjf6vqgxd-python3-3.8.12-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_abi/registry.py", line 354, in _get_registration
    coder = super()._get_registration(mapping, type_str)
  File "/nix/store/czlg5442w24w6mbam890wcgkjf6vqgxd-python3-3.8.12-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_abi/registry.py", line 336, in _get_registration
    value = mapping.find(type_str)
  File "/nix/store/czlg5442w24w6mbam890wcgkjf6vqgxd-python3-3.8.12-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_abi/registry.py", line 89, in find
    raise NoEntriesFound("No matching entries for '{}' in {}".format(
eth_abi.exceptions.NoEntriesFound: No matching entries for 'tuple' in decoder registry
WARNING:__main__:Retrying events for block range 1295961 - 1295981 (20) failed with No matching entries for 'tuple' in decoder registry, retrying in 3.0 seconds
```

I was connected through websockets,

#### How can it be fixed?

I don't know. I tried this version but it didn't fix anything: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/pull/2211